# Как сохранить в select значение option при обновлении?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Всем привет!

Как сохранить выбор селекта после обновления страницы?

```html
<form method="POST">
<select name='sort' id="sortID">
   <option value="0">Все</option>
   <option value="5">Дерматологи</option>
 </select>
<input type="submit" value="Показать">
</form>
```

Comment: Выбирайте: 
1) на стороне клиента :cookie \ localStorage \ applicationStorage \ ....
2) на сервере: cookie \ session \ database \ ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С использованием localStorage так:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 var item = localStorage.getItem('sortId');
 var select = document.getElementById("sortID");
 select.value = item;
});
function submitForm(){
 var select = document.getElementById("sortID");
 var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
 localStorage.setItem('sortId', value);
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" onsubmit="submitForm()">
 <select name='sort' id="sortID">
    <option value="0">Все</option>
    <option value="5">Дерматологи</option>
  </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Показать">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как альтернатива на чистом php - можно использовать `cookie`
Если именно при перезагрузке страницы(важно)
Вариант tCode с js будет покомфортней.

Пример:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: 640kb
 * Date: 22/01/2020
 * Time: 17:46
 */

$sort = "";
if(isset($_POST['sort'])) {
    $sort = $_POST['sort'];
    setcookie("sort", $sort);
}
if(isset($_COOKIE['sort'])){
    $sort = $_COOKIE['sort'];
};

?>

<form method="POST">
    <select name='sort' id="sortID">
        <option value="0" <?php if($sort == "0"){ echo 'selected';}?>>Все</option>
        <option value="5" <?php if($sort == "5"){ echo 'selected';}?>>Дерматологи</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Показать">
</form>
```